# Is there a way to retrieve the minimum value of a datatype in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve the latest date stored in any of three columns in a row.

This query works fine when all three dates are not `NULL`:

```
SELECT GREATEST(date_A, date_B, date_C) FROM mytable
```

But when any of those values are `NULL`, [`GREATEST` returns `NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

A way around this would be to use:

```
SELECT GREATEST(
  COALESCE(date_A, '1000-01-01'),
  COALESCE(date_B, '1000-01-01'),
  COALESCE(date_C, '1000-01-01')
) FROM mytable
```

This works because ['1000-01-01' is the minimum value of the `DATE` datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). For readability's sake, however I'd much rather express the query in terms of a `MIN_VALUE` function or constant.

Does something like this exist in MySQL?

Comment: According to me, you can set default value of date fields like `0000-00-00` so that if it is passed NULL then automatically field value is the default value mentioned above so even you don't have to use `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` etc. functions

Comment: I would prefer `GREATEST(COALESCE(date_A, date_B, date_C), COALESCE(date_B, date_C, date_A), COALESCE(date_C, date_A, date_B))`—no need for "magic" values, but sadly still somewhat verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function or constant in MySQL. The obvious one to have would be MAXINT, but even that is not available.

If possible, my suggestion would be, as mentioned in comments, to not allow NULL values in the column. Instead use MySQL's zero value for dates which is `0000-00-00`, and will work as expected with `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```
mysql> SELECT GREATEST ('2015-01-01', '2041-11-13', '1844-05-30', '0000-00-00');
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GREATEST ('2015-01-01', '2041-11-13', '1844-05-30', '0000-00-00') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2041-11-13                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LEAST ('2015-01-01', '2041-11-13', '1844-05-30', '0000-00-00');
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| LEAST ('2015-01-01', '2041-11-13', '1844-05-30', '0000-00-00') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0000-00-00                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @miken mentions this is not possible unfortunately. YOu can consider declaring a variable

```
SET @MIN_DATE = '1001-01-01';
SELECT GREATEST(
  COALESCE(DATE_A, @MIN_DATE),
  COALESCE(DATE_B, @MIN_DATE),
  COALESCE(DATE_C, @MIN_DATE)
) FROM mytable
```

Still not very pretty, but at least it is somewhat more readable

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2374/2)